# Accessing databases using different threads - java

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I ran the reader () method and reader2 () using two different threads and using the main thread.

After checking the times for the two cases, I realized that there were no significant differences.

My doubts: the access to the basics of oracle through JDBC data, it is only possible to make a query at a time?

Thank you.

```
public class ReadingTime {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    //reader("pessoas");
    //reader("pessoas_dw");

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            reader("pessoas");
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            reader2("PESSOAS_DW");
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

}

public static void reader(String s){
    long tempoInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();
    MyConnection conn = new MyConnection("oracle", "localhost", "1521", "orcl", "username1", "password1");
    conn.openConnection();
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet tabela1 = conn.executeQuery(st, "select * from "+s);
    int i = 1;
    try {
        while(tabela1.next()){
            i++;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Thread 1");
    System.out.println(i);
    long tempoFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println( tempoFinal - tempoInicial );
    System.out.println("____________________________");

}

public static void reader2(String s){
    long tempoInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();
    MyConnection conn = new MyConnection("oracle", "localhost", "1521", "orcl", "username2", "password2");
    conn.openConnection();
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet tabela1 = conn.executeQuery(st, "select * from "+s);
    int i = 1;
    try {
        while(tabela1.next()){
            i++;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Thread 2");
    System.out.println(i);
    long tempoFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println( tempoFinal - tempoInicial );
    System.out.println("__________________________");

}
```

Comment: How long does the query take? If it is quite slow, then running two queries in parallel (assuming the database itself is up to it) could be faster. If it is very fast, you won't notice a difference.

Comment: Oracle can have as many simultaneous accesses to a database as there are connections.  Oracle has multithreading mechanisms which allow you to specify concurrency policies for such environments.  Moreover, RDBMS has mechanisms to 'retire' liveness failures should deadlocks occur.  So, no ... Oracle and many other RDBMS with multithreading allow more than one query at a time.

Comment: As per the "I" in the ACID principle, you can run as many concurrent queries as the database supports (depends on your DB), and the result should be consistent in the end.

Comment: I dont think and it would not be true and correct statement, if you will say Oracle RDBMS wont allow to use it to achieve concurrency and parallel execution of query on same DB object. Until you apply some locking to control consistency.

Comment: @KaroLa: Oracle, and many other RDBMS servers, have concurrent access mechanisms built into the database software to control the integrity and consistency of its own data (these are the so-called ACID-compliant databases).  The JDBC classes in Java, however, are not thread-safe, but the OP's two threads have each created their own connections and these connection objects are thread-confined.  There is therefore no problem of thread-safety in his program as written.

Comment: @scottb :Yes I am aware, I am from java background working with Oracle since last 5 years,
I Know java and connection mechanism its not thread safe we need to manage by our self or we should use some framework or API.
Ricardo Faria
you can refer this link may be it is use full: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776674/how-to-execute-multiple-queries-in-parallel-instead-of-sequentially

Comment: @Thilo - without the 2 threads the program takes roughly 70000 milisec wich is the sames as the with 2 thread.

Comment: How long does each query take separately? If it is 70000 ms + 10 ms then running them in parallel won't do much.

Comment: Calling only reader() - 
Calling only reader2()-
calling reader() in separate thread -
calling reader2() in separate thread -

Comment: I ran new tests now, this are the results:
Calling only reader() - 38220
Calling only reader2()- 37206
calling reader() in separate thread - 37311
calling reader2() in separate thread - 36416
Two threads at same time - 78202

It seems to be competing for some resource

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna make a guess here.
You don't close the resultset, nor the statement, nor the connection (particularly not closing the connection).

My guess is that the MyConnection (which we can't see) might be reusing the previous connection when it is on the same (main) thread.

So, assuming the connection establishment time is much greater than the resultset iteration, it would make sense.

Try to close the rs, st and conn to see if it makes a difference.