# How to execute multiple sql query parallel in java

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, java-8

I have 3 method which is returning a List of result and my sql query execute in each method and returning a list of result .I want to execute all 3 method parallel so it will not wait to complete of one and another . I saw one stachoverflow post but its not working.
that link is [[How to execute multiple queries in parallel instead of sequentially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776674/how-to-execute-multiple-queries-in-parallel-instead-of-sequentially][1])
[[Execute multiple queries in parallel via Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33649902/execute-multiple-queries-in-parallel-via-streams][1])

I want to solve using java 8 features.
But the above link how I can call multiple method please tell me.

Comment: what is the error you get with the answer in the link ?

Answer (score 1):

[Execute multiple queries in parallel via Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33649902/execute-multiple-queries-in-parallel-via-streams) works for your task. Here is a sample code which demonstrates it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create Stream of tasks:
    Stream<Supplier<List<String>>> tasks = Stream.of(
            () -> getServerListFromDB(),
            () -> getAppListFromDB(),
            () -> getUserFromDB());

    List<List<String>> lists = tasks
            // Supply all the tasks for execution and collect CompletableFutures
            .map(CompletableFuture::supplyAsync).collect(Collectors.toList())
            // Join all the CompletableFutures to gather the results
            .stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(lists);
}

private static List<String> getUserFromDB() {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 3));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " getUser");
    return Arrays.asList("User1", "User2", "User3");
}

private static List<String> getAppListFromDB() {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 3));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " getAppList");
    return Arrays.asList("App1", "App2", "App3");
}

private static List<String> getServerListFromDB() {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 3));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " getServer");
    return Arrays.asList("Server1", "Server2", "Server3");
}
```

The output is:

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1 getServer
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3 getUser
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2 getAppList
[[Server1, Server2, Server3], [App1, App2, App3], [User1, User2, User3]]
```

You can see that default ForkJoinPool.commonPool is used and each get* method is executed from separate thread in this pool. You just need to run your SQL queries inside these get* methods

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()` can and should be omitted

Answer (score -1):

The solution from Alex won't work in an expected way. CompletableFuture executes effects one after another. You will have to run parallel streams for this or use CompletableFuture with parallelStream